# kwargs does not pass key-value parameters inside function, but does outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, keyword-argument

I want to create an empty `pandas.DataFrame` and add some columns to it using `**kwargs`.  The `DataFrame` remains empty when I try to populate it inside the function `make_new_data_frame` (I tried adding columns one by one, and all at once using kwargs).  However, if I return `kwargs` and `err_df2` from the function, the operation works (in a jupyter notebook).  How can I get this to work inside the function, and why doesn't it?  MWE below

```
from pandas import DataFrame
def make_data_frame():
    df = DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':[1.1,2.2,3.3]})
    return df
def make_new_data_frame():
    df = make_data_frame()
    err_df = DataFrame()
    kwargs = {}
    for c in df.columns:
        if c == 'foo':
            continue
        err_df.assign(**{c: df['foo'] - df[c]})
        kwargs[c] = df['foo'] - df[c]
    err_df2 = DataFrame()
    err_df2.assign(**kwargs)
    return err_df, err_df2, kwargs
err_df, err_df2, kwargs = make_new_data_frame()
print(err_df,'\n')
print(err_df2,'\n')
print(raw_data,'\n')
err_df2.assign(**kwargs)
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [] 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [] 

{'bar': 0   -0.1
1   -0.2
2   -0.3
dtype: float64} 

Out[26]:
bar
0   -0.1
1   -0.2
2   -0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) docs:

> Assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones.

So you need to do something like this inside the function:

```
err_df2 = err_df2.assign(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify an assumption built into your question, the dataframe is actually empty in *both* of your cases, inside and outside. It's not doing what you're expecting outside the function, either.

`assign` does not change the dataframe in place. The REPL environment is adding to the confusion that `assign` could be doing that, but it's not.

When you execute `err_df2.assign(**kwargs)` in your last line, the supposedly "correct" output that you see is just the new copy that results from the `assign`, printed in the interactive session. `err_df2` itself is not changed.

So when you print the actual `err_df2` dataframe—whether created "inside" or "outside"—you are seeing the empty `DataFrame()` you initialized, without any changes from `assign`.